# Does Visual Studio 2015 have a "Save a Copy As" feature?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Does Visual Studio 2015 have a "Save A Copy As" feature for files, like IDLE and Notepad++? Currently, if I had somethning like `test.cpp` in a solution, I use "Save As" to save it to `test2.cpp`. `test.cpp` would be gone, so I'd just re-open it.

It's not much of a hassle, I just want to know if "Save a Copy As" feature or something like it exists in VS for convenience.

Comment: Have you tried? Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition is free.  Microsoft also has FREE VMs which include VS2015

Comment: @Ramhound Ya. I have VS 2015 with me right now. I can't find anything in the File menu. I was wondering if the feature existed somewhere else.

Comment: You were wondering if "Save As" was hidden somewhere else other the. The File context menu, that would be a, "no it's not"

Comment: @Ramhound Oh ok. Thanks. Would've been nice to have it though.

Comment: That's why I asked if you had looked...

Comment: not exactly what you ask for, but you can just  copy paste any file in solution explorer

Comment: This is an old question, but it's still annoying how Save As in VS is implemented.  I can't imagine why they thought that Save As always means remove the previous file from the project.  It's like they thought Save As was Rename.

Comment: @ScottGartner I saw your comment when I was looking back at this. I tried what you did in my VS 2015, and I still have both files. Are you sure you were using File->Save As? I don't see any other save options there.

Comment: @DragonautX I just tested this in VS 2019 and the same behavior is there.  Note that this isn't about deleting files from the file system (that doesn't happen with save as) but is about removing the original file from the open project (replacing it with the new copy).  The expected functionality (IMHO) would be that both the old file and the new file would be in the project after save as (the same as happens if you copy/paste a file in the project, both of them end up in the project, if VS wanted to be consistent the paste would replace the old file (so "f - Copy.cs" would replace "f.cs").

Comment: @ScottGartner I have 2019 too, but I still couldn't see it. I put a screenshot in my dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/utq5gm3rmrsrxai/vs-save-as.jpg?dl=0 Maybe you can see how I'm misinterpreting it? What I'm seeing so far, the "save-as-test.cpp" in the screenshot isn't replacing anything in my test project.